# Multi-Password Archive

Tags: file, encryption, passwords, archive

I'd like to know if exists a type of archive which uses multiple passwords to show some files instead of other.

For example if the archive contains **a**, **b** and **c** :

- With password **p** I can see only **a** and **b**.
- With password **q** I can see only **c**.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You could put **a** and **b** in one encrypted archive, **c** an another with a different password, and then archive these two together into one file.

Comment: Unfortunatly I'd like that this process to be "trasparent" to the final user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that TrueCrypt can do this using [hidden volumes](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/hidden-volume#Y18).

Comment: Great! I hoped to find a "normal archive", but a virtual partition file is fine too!